# What is a good way to implement the equivalent of Haskell's "or" function using Streams in Java

Tags: java, haskell, stream

I'm looking for an equivalent to [Haskell's "or" function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:or) in Java using Streams.

This version does not return when given an infinite stream:

```
    public static Boolean or(Stream<Boolean> bs) {
      return bs.reduce(false, (x, y) -> x || y);
    }
```

This version does not run because the bs stream is used twice:

```
    public static Boolean or(Stream<Boolean> bs) {
    Optional<Boolean> b0 = bs.findFirst();

    if (b0.isPresent()) {
        return  b0.get() || or(bs.skip(1));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm new to Java, so any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`Stream#anyMatch(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) with a `Predicate` that returns the value itself.

```
// assuming there are no null values
boolean or = booleans.anyMatch(b -> b); // will only match if value is true
```

Similarly to what is described in the Haskell documentation for `or` that you linked, if the `Stream` is infinite, it cannot return `false`. It will continue to consume the `Stream` if all it sees is `false` values.

This is a short-circuiting operation. It will (actually, it can, but doesn't have to) return `true` as soon as it finds a `true` value.

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  So the function that works for me is:   public static Boolean or(Stream<Boolean> bs) {return bs.anyMatch(b -> b);}